# Delete a 3-entity (one-to-many-to-one) association with Symfony 3 using Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, symfony-3.2

This is my very first question!

I have two entities that I want to relate: `Product` and `Category`. A product may have multiple categories and a category may correspond to many products. I've decided to implement this relationship as a 3-class association, having an intermediate `ProductCategory` entity, as shown in the image below. This give me flexibility to add properties to the association in the future.

[Representation of my tree-class association](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjQjb.png)

I want to assign existing categories to existing products. **I want to establish the relationship from within the entities themselves**. I am able to do that within the `Product` entity, using a setter method that receives an array of `Category` entities, and creates a new `ProductCategory` entity for each category passed. The procedure is as follows:

```
//Product.php

/**
 * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $categories
 * @return \TestBundle\Entity\Product 
 */
public function setCategories($categories) {
    $productCategoryReplacement = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $newProductCategory = new ProductCategory();
        $newProductCategory->setProduct($this);
        $newProductCategory->setCategory($category);
        $productCategoryReplacement[] = $newProductCategory;
    }
    $this->productCategory = $productCategoryReplacement;

    return $this;
}
```

Note that I clear the `ProductCategory` collection before adding new ones; in this way only those categories selected in the form are saved to the database.

**My problem is** that Doctrine doesn't delete the records from the database before inserting the new ones. This is fine when no categories were assigned to the product but I get an `Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1-1' for key 'PRIMARY'` when trying to update the association. I've checked the Symfony debug panel, in the Doctrine section, and no DELETE statement is ever executed prior to the INSERTs.

Is it possible to delete related entities from within an entity? If not, then why is it possible to add new ones? Thanks in advance.

---

My entities are as follows:

Product.php:

```
namespace TestBundle\Entity;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="TestBundle\Repository\ProductRepository")
 */
class Product {

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductCategory", mappedBy="product", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $productCategory;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct() {
    $this->productCategory = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * @param \TestBundle\Entity\ProductCategory $productCategory
 * @return Product
 */
public function addProductCategory(\TestBundle\Entity\ProductCategory $productCategory) {
    $this->productCategory[] = $productCategory;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param \TestBundle\Entity\ProductCategory $productCategory
 */
public function removeProductCategory(\TestBundle\Entity\ProductCategory $productCategory) {
    $this->productCategory->removeElement($productCategory);
}

/**
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getProductCategory() {
    return $this->productCategory;
}
/**
 * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $categories
 * @return \TestBundle\Entity\Product 
 */
public function setCategories($categories) {
    $productCategoryReplacement = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $newProductCategory = new ProductCategory();
        $newProductCategory->setProduct($this);
        $newProductCategory->setCategory($category);
        $productCategoryReplacement[] = $newProductCategory;
    }
    $this->productCategory = $productCategoryReplacement;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 */
public function getCategories() {
    $categories = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    foreach ($this->getProductCategory() as $pc) {
        $categories[] = $pc->getCategory();
    }
    return $categories;
}
}
```

Category.php:

```
namespace TestBundle\Entity;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="category")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="TestBundle\Repository\CategoryRepository")
 */
class Category {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductCategory", mappedBy="category", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $productCategory;
}
```

ProductCategory.php

```
namespace TestBundle\Entity;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="product_category")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="TestBundle\Repository\ProductCategoryRepository")
 */
class ProductCategory {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="productCategory")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $product;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="productCategory")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $category;
}
```

My `Product` form is generated as follows:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('name')
        ->add('categories', EntityType::class, array(
           'class' => 'TestBundle:Category',
           'choice_label' => 'name',
           'expanded' => true,
           'multiple' => true,
    ));
}
```

Note that I use a `categories` field name that will be populated with categories taken from `Category` entity. The form returns an array of `Category` objects that I use to generate `ProductCategory` entities in the `setCategories()` method within `Product.php`.

```
/**
 * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $categories
 * @return \TestBundle\Entity\Product 
 */
public function setCategories($categories) {
    $productCategoryReplacement = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $newProductCategory = new ProductCategory();
        $newProductCategory->setProduct($this);
        $newProductCategory->setCategory($category);
        $productCategoryReplacement[] = $newProductCategory;
    }
    $this->productCategory = $productCategoryReplacement;

    return $this;
}
```

**EDIT 1:**

I don't have a `categories` field in `Product`, I only have a `getCategories()` and `setCategories()` methods. As shown in my form type code, I add an `EntityType` field of class `Categories`, that maps to the `categories` property (that doesn't actually exist). In this way I'm able to show existing categories as checkboxes an the product's categories are checked correctly.

**EDIT 2: POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

I ended up following Sam Jenses's suggestion. I created a service as follows:

File: `src/TestBundle/Service/CategoryCleaner.php`

```
namespace TestBundle\Service;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use TestBundle\Entity\Product;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class CategoryCleaner {

    /**
     *
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em) {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function cleanCategories(Product $product, Request $request) {
        if ($this->em == null) {
            throw new Exception('Entity manager parameter must not be null');
        }
        if ($request == null) {
            throw new Exception('Request parameter must not be null');
        }

        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
            $categories = $this->em->getRepository('TestBundle:ProductCategory')->findByProduct($product);
            foreach ($categories as $category) {
                $this->em->remove($category);
            }
            $this->em->flush();
        }
    }
}
```

In the `cleanCategories` method, which receives the current Product and Request as parameters, all entries of `ProductCategory` which correspond to `Product` are removed, only in case of a POST request.

The service is registered as follows:

File `app/config/services.yml`

```
services:
    app.category_cleaner:
        class: TestBundle\Service\CategoryCleaner
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
```

The service must be called from the controller **before** `handleRequest($request)`, that is, before the new categories are added. If not, we get a duplicate entry exception.

Edit method from file `TestBundle/Controller/ProductController.php`

```
public function editAction(Request $request, Product $product) {
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($product);
    $editForm = $this->createForm('TestBundle\Form\ProductType', $product);

    $this->container->get('app.category_cleaner')->cleanCategories($product, $request);

    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('product_edit', array('id' => $product->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('product/edit.html.twig', array(
                'product' => $product,
                'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
                'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
```

Please validate my approach.

Comment: do you need to delete all ProductCategory inside setCategories?

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri not every single `ProductCategory`, only those who are related to `Product`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create an intermediate service, in which you can also use doctrine to remove the existing entities

Comment: I've edited my question to show how I implemented the service

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have inside your entity some methods like:

```
addCategory
removeCategory
getCategory
```

and also

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->categories = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

So inside your function you can do:

```
public function setCategories($categories) {
    $productCategoryReplacement = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();

    foreach ($this->categories as $category) {
        $this->removeCategory($category);
    }

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $newProductCategory = new ProductCategory();
        $newProductCategory->setProduct($this);
        $newProductCategory->setCategory($category);
        $productCategoryReplacement[] = $newProductCategory;
    }
    $this->productCategory = $productCategoryReplacement;

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: I'm unable to delete categories, Doctrine does not persist them.